# Running tomcat before opening an internet explorer tab

Tags: batch-file, tomcat, cmd

I would like to start the [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) server in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) then opening an Internet Explorer tab. The problem is if I start tomcat IE will not start but if I open the tab before starting the server, I have to wait until it starts then refresh the page to access it. I want to automate this procedure, because I have to do it often and every time I have to open a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) and paste the path then run `startup.bat`.

I have tried switching the two commands, but in that case, IE will not open.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
start iexplore.exe "http://my-link-to-access"
cd ..
cd C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat\bin
startup.bat
```

Expected: `startup.bat` starting and after 4-5 sec (bcs the server needs that time to start up) IE opens and I can see the page I want to access.

Actual: IE starts up and it tries to connect to the server, in the meantime, the server is starting. After the server is up, I have to refresh the page to work properly.

Comment: start tomcat, then timeout the script until it started up, then run iexplore.

Answer (score 0):

I typically see that connections to tomcat that come in through the startup phase will be paused until startup has completed.

This suggests that a switch of the startup order, with a static pause between the two, might help. Try this (pseudocode, I'm not running windows) in your Batchfile

```
\path\to\tomcat\startup.bat
timeout 5
iexplore.exe http://localhost:8080
```

I consider 5 seconds to be much more than enough.

Comment: Well, it is `timeout 5` in a batch file (there is no `sleep`, and `pause` does not accept any arguments, it just waits for a key press)...